# Cannot connect to SQL Server on local machine using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I wonder if anyone can help me. I'm creating an application in PHP and am using a SQL server database on my local computer to develop the application. The only problem is I cannot connect to the database. My code looks like:

```
<?php
$serverName = "LIAMJAY-PC\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ONEDB");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

to connect to the database. However, everytime I run the code I keep getting a 18456 error code. Does anybody know what my problem is and if so, what is the solution???

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try supplying `UID` and `PWD` as follows:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ONEDB", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
```

Error code 18456 occurs when you are using SQL Server Authentication and the login name and password are incorrect, or even when the user is disabled or locked.

Comment: Are you able to login through a SQL Client using Windows Authentication?

Comment: Just tried adding a username and password but i get an error message shown in next comment.

Comment: I am able to login through Windows Authentication in sql management but not in PHP

Comment: I'm getting error: Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'local'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'local'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'local'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'local'))

Comment: Please check that the port is not other than 1433 which is the default.  Check if you can telnet to that port.

Comment: Checked all of that and there seems to be no problem